# SQL request with variable equal to current row column value in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi, just registered to ask this since I did not find answers after some research :

My table my_table has several columns, but only two matter here : id (integer, primary key, ...) and children (varchar that contains one or several `{"number":"number"}` as seen in the example below)

```cpp
id | children
0  | {"0":"0"}
1  | {"1":"1"} {"2":"2"} {"3":"3"}
2  | {"2":"2"}
3  | {"3":"3"}
4  | {"4":"4"}
5  | {"5":"5"} {"6":"6"}
6  | {"6":"6"}
```

You can see that for any choosen row, the column children will always contain at least one occurence of `{"number":"number"}` where '`number`' is  equal to the value of column id of this row.

Sometimes it contains more than one occurence of `{"number":"number"}` with numbers of other rows' id.

I would like to build a SQL query that returns all rows :

- where there is only one occurence of `{"number":"number"}` in the children column
- and for each row, verify that the value `'number'` in `{"number":"number"}` is equal to the row's id value.

I tried :

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table 

WHERE children=CONCAT('{"', my_table.id, '":"', my_table.id, '"}')
```

This returns nothing obviously...
I'm still searching but I guess some more experienced users will have a solution :)

EDIT1 : I wrote '=' instead of ':' in my query and never noticed it xD Thank you. The query is now correct and working as intended.

Comment: It is very bad db design to store formated data

Comment: You confused a `:` with a `=` in your query.

Comment: It is not my database, I must work with what's already here tho :/
The formatted data is made automatically and not filled by a human however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all records with an ID mismatch (you had an equal sign where it must be a colon):

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE children NOT LIKE CONCAT('%{"', my_table.id, '":"', my_table.id, '"}%');
```

Select all records with only one pair:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE children NOT LIKE '{%{%';
```

Combine the two somehow if you want a cobined result :-)

Comment: I selected your answer since that was the typo error that was causing this, thx for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work.  There must be some other characters that you are missing.

Here is another method:

```
where children like '%{%' and
      children not like '%{%{%' and
      children like concat('%"', id, '":%') and
      children like concat('%:"', id, '"%')
```

This is just comparing each section of the pattern.

You might also try:

```
WHERE children LIKE CONCAT('%{"', my_table.id, '":"', my_table.id, '"}%') AND
      children NOT LIKE '%{%{%';
```

The most likely problem are spaces (or other characters) at the beginning or end of the string.  This allows those, but doesn't allow multiple items in the list.

Comment: No, the problem is not spaces, but simply that the separator should be the colon instead of the equal sign :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with very bad db design notice.

your problem is maybe very simple - see the change in concat function

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 

WHERE children=CONCAT('{"', my_table.id, '":"', my_table.id, '"}')
```